# How do I eliminate the additional row for aggregate column in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to do some aggregation of fields and I get an additional row on the aggregate column- in this case 'sum'. How do I get rid of this? This makes it difficult to process this dataframe in subsequent processing

```
import pandas as pd
Grade=[['A',1],['A',2],['A',10],['B',4],['B',2],['C',3],['D',10],['D',5],['D',1]]
Grade_df=pd.DataFrame(Grade,columns=['grade','count'])    
Grade_Aggregate=Grade_df.groupby(['grade']).agg({'count':['sum']}).reset_index()
```

Grade_Aggregate

```
  grade count
          sum
0     A    13
1     B     6
2     C     3
3     D    16
```

Comment: Thanks- this works perfect. Would you want to add this as answer

Comment: Added it as an answer. Glad to have helped ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Groupby.sum` here directly.

```
Grade_df.groupby('grade', as_index=False)['count'].sum()

  grade  count
0     A     13
1     B      6
2     C      3
3     D     16
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the 'Sum':

```
Grade_Aggregate.columns=[i[0] for i in Grade_Aggregate.columns]
```

If you want it to be appended to the column name:

```
Grade_Aggregate.columns=["_".join(i) for i in Grade_Aggregate.columns]
```